# Adding google sign in button to my laravel project

Tags: laravel, google-signin

I have a laravel project with laravel authentication and I want to add google sign in button in the project after user pass laravel main auth, then I want to have second check using google account.

The issue I'm struggling with is after user successfully login, I want to have pop up for google account check without showing google sign in button.

Google sign in button integration is working, I want to add trigger to the click event, but no luck.

I am using this docs: [google docs link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

And want to trigger click event like this:
`$('#signinButton').trigger('click');`

Does anyone know what's the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don t just use laravel socialite instead?

https://github.com/laravel/socialite

Comment: ok, using socialite package,is it possibleto add  social auth to laravel basic authentication, I mean aftyer user login with laravel basic auth, next step should be socialite authentication. Is it possible to do?

Comment: I think you can do that. The gmail api returns and id and email. You can valildate that in you database with your user data.